# How check if the current OpenGL context runs on a Geforce card?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

How can I check whether an OpenGL context runs on a Geforce card? I need to run differnt code depending on whether it is running on a Geforce card, Quadro or AMD card and need a way to detect this.

Comment: Can you get the name of the different graphic cards installed on the computer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution may be suitable

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetString.xml

You can use this to return the vender and version. Im not sure if each card is explicitly different with OpenGL or if a certain version by each vender is all you will need

Comment: I'll try this. However, I think this will just print out "Nvidia..." and the opengl version, it doesn't actually say what the cards name is.

Comment: The vender and version should dictate what the card can do when it comes to opengl.

Comment: I don't need to know what the card can do (there are better ways to check that than parsing strings), I need to specifically know whether it is a Geforce card or not.

Comment: ask the operating system - not the graphics driver. It should give you the answer.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand why though, the card shouldnt make a difference to what OpenGL code can run on it surely? That comes down to what version of OpenGL and the vendor of the card? If its not to differentiate between what opengl calls then what purpose is it for?

Comment: @Moore91: It makes a difference on how the drivers are implemented and its performance characteristics, e.g. on a Geforce card you should do a buffer copy before `glReadPixels` (2x perf diff), while this is not needed on Quadro cards, and is a lot slower on AMD cards.

Comment: I see. I've found glGetString(GL_RENDERER) to return the name of the video card, but it displays some of its features, as well.

Comment: @Moore91: I guess that could be good enough. Will try it later.